# Picking the threshold value for list elements in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `Cb`. If any element of `Cb` is greater than `threshold_Cb`, I want to be that element equal to `threshold_Cb`. But I am getting error. I present the expected output.

```
Cb=[[0.001,
  7.557543577091797e-06,
  1656.90]]

threshold_Cb=10.0

if Cb > threshold_Cb:
    Cb = threshold_Cb
    print(Cb)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    if Cb > threshold_Cb:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

The expected output is

```
Cb=[[0.001,
  7.557543577091797e-06,
  10.0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over every item in the nested list and compare them individually:

```
Cb=[[0.001,
  7.557543577091797e-06,
  1656.90]]

threshold_Cb=10.0
# Iterating over the first list within the nested list you have
for index, value  in enumerate(Cb[0]):
    # checking if the value is above treshold
    if value > threshold_Cb:
        # Reassigning the value with index
        Cb[0][index] = threshold_Cb
print(Cb)
```

Output:

```
[[0.001, 7.557543577091797e-06, 10.0]]
```

Otherwise your "if" statement is comparing if a nested list is larger than an integer and that is not a meaningful comparison. Hence your error message.

When Cb has more than one lists inside it you can do this:

```
# iterating over nested lists inside Cb
for lst_index, lst in enumerate(Cb):
    # Iterating over the nested list values
    for value_index, value  in enumerate(lst):
        # checking if the value is above treshold
        if value > threshold_Cb:
            # Reassigning the value with index
            Cb[lst_index][value_index] = threshold_Cb
```

Comment: Cb is a list of lists. This "solution" only allows for one sub-list

Comment: This "solution" illustrates that some form of iteration is needed to active the desired result. [0] can be turned into [ i ] and iterated over. You will be a fool to prematurely optimise a solution without having any context on what you should optimise for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
new_Cb = [[x if x <= threshold_Cb else threshold_Cb for x in Cb[0]]]
```

Comprehensions like the above are more efficient than loops. `Cb[0]` is required because you have a nested List and the `[[ ...]]` in the above is because you want a nested List.

gives

```
[[0.001, 7.557543577091797e-06, 10.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested list (aka a list inside a list). When you run your code, it is iterating over the outer list (`Cb`). This means that will try to compare

`[0.001, 7.557543577091797e-06, 1656.90]` with your threshold (`threshold_Cb=10.0`), and this is the source of your error.
What you need is to iterate over elements in `[0.001,   7.557543577091797e-06,   1656.90]` and compare them to `threshold_Cb`.

## 1) Solution:

```
   Cb=[[0.001,
      7.557543577091797e-06,
      1656.90]]
    
    threshold_Cb=10.0
    
    for inner_list in Cb:
        for index, element in enumerate(inner_list): 
            if element > threshold_Cb:
                inner_list[index] = threshold_Cb
    
    
    print(Cb)
[[0.001, 7.557543577091797e-06, 10.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify Cb *in situ* rather than create a new list I suggest:

```
Cb = [
    [
        0.001,
        7.557543577091797e-06,
        1656.90
    ]
]

threshold_Cb = 10.0

for e in Cb:
    e[:] = [min(v, threshold_Cb) for v in e]

print(Cb)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.001, 7.557543577091797e-06, 10.0]]
```

**Note:**

Concise code (such as this) isn't necessarily most efficient and this is certainly one of those cases